# Ethernet symbol shows connected in topbar on Ubuntu even when disconnected

Tags: gnome, wayland

While connecting to ethernet, the top bar shows the accurate wired connection symbol. If I manually turn off the wired connection in settings, the symbol disappears as expected. However, if I physically remove the ethernet port, the connected symbol continues to show indefinitely until I connect to a different network (Wifi or bluetooth) at which point it refreshes.

This does not seem to be a problem with NetworkManager as it detects all connections accurately but rather with Gnome 45 detecting this change.

What can I do to debug this issue?

This is the symbol I am referring to [connected wired network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3GUi.png)